# How can i get the position number of an element?

Tags: html, firefox, dom, firebug, traversal

Is there any plugin in firefox or function in firebug or something else, that lets me se the position number of a specific element?

If i for example want to know the what position a specific TD element has compared to all the TD's in the document.

EXAMPLE:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td> (0)
<td></td> (1)
<td></td> (2)
<td></td> (3)
<td></td> (And so on...)
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td> <------ WHAT IS THE POSITION NUMBER OF THIS TD?
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example]

The webdeveloper toolbar in firefox has a tool that lets you see the index number of all DIV's. This is what i need but for other elements, not just DIV.
[image: Web developer toolbar]

*PS. I was inspired by the correct answer and i made my own solution:*

```
var dom = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var x;
for(x = 0; x < dom.length; x++)
{
    dom[x].innerHTML = dom[x].nodeName + '[' + x + '] ' + '(' + dom[x].innerHTML + ')';
    dom[x].style.color = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: With jQuery: `$( 'td' ).index( yourTD )` or `$( yourTD ).index( 'td' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the following will do as you need:

```
$('li').each(

function(i) {
    $(this).text('list element ' + i);
});

function indexAmongSiblings(elem) {
    if (!elem) {
        return false;
    }
    var that = elem;
    var parent = that.parentNode;
    var siblings = parent.childNodes;
    var elemSiblings = [];
    for (var s = 0, numberOf = siblings.length; s < numberOf; s++) {
        if (siblings[s].nodeName != '#text' && siblings[s].tagName != undefined) {
            elemSiblings.push(siblings[s]);
        }
    }
    for (var e=0,l=elemSiblings.length; e<l; e++){
        if (elemSiblings[e] == elem){
            console.log('Element number: ' + e + ' among its siblings.');
        }
    }
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        indexAmongSiblings(this);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qPhcA/2/).

---

**Edited** the above in order to show how to assign the element's index, amongst its siblings, to a variable:

```
$('li').each(

function(i) {
    $(this).text('list element ' + i);
});

function indexAmongSiblings(elem) {
    if (!elem) {
        return false;
    }
    var that = elem;
    var parent = that.parentNode;
    var siblings = parent.childNodes;
    var elemSiblings = [];
    for (var s = 0, numberOf = siblings.length; s < numberOf; s++) {
        if (siblings[s].nodeName != '#text' && siblings[s].tagName != undefined) {
            elemSiblings.push(siblings[s]);
        }
    }
    for (var e=0,l=elemSiblings.length; e<l; e++){
        if (elemSiblings[e] == elem){
            // the following returns the index-point amongst siblings
            return e;
        }
    }
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var thisIndex = indexAmongSiblings(this);
        // the thisIndex variable now holds the returned index-point
    };
}
```

---

**Edited** in response to comments left on other answers, by OP:

> I want the number/sequence position of a specific element(e.g ) compared to equal elements(e.g ) in the whole DOM.

[Citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555061/how-can-i-get-the-position-number-of-an-element/8555613#comment-10602708).

The following function will get, and return, the index position of the clicked element amongst other tags of the same type in the document (which is actually somewhat easier than the above):

```
function indexAmongSameTags(elem) {
    if (!elem || !elem.tagName) {
        return false;
    }

    var thisIs = elem.tagName.toLowerCase(),
        sameAs = document.getElementsByTagName(thisIs);

    for (var i=0,len=sameAs.length; i<len; i++){
        if (sameAs[i] == elem){
            console.log('You clicked ' + thisIs + ' of index position "' + i + '" among ' + len + ' other ' + thisIs + ' elements');
            return i;
        }
    }

}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var indexPosition = indexAmongSameTags(this);
        console.log(indexPosition);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qPhcA/6/).

References:

- [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes).
- [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault).
- [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation).
- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode).
- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: AAaaaaawwwww Yeeeaahhh! Works perfect :-)

Just paste it in the firebug console and it works, nice. Since there is no built in tool for the job, i will use this script, Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Sorry, I've misunderstood your question. Here is the answer then:

1. Open your firebug
2. Select your element with the inspect tool
3. Once you clicked, one the right side click the dom link
4. See the cell index there.

Like this:

[image]

---

With javascript you can get the numbers of tds.

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); // this will return every td in the document. 
if (console && console.log)
   console.log(tds.length);
else
   alert(tds.length);
```

The example above will print the totoal number of td elements in your document. However, if you want a particular td, you should give that td an identifier. For instance assume your html file is like:

```
...
<td id="your_td"></td>
...
```

Now with javascript you can:

```
var td = document.getElementById('your_td'); // this will return the td 
// if you want its position you can: 
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) { 

   if (tds[i] === td) 
       alert(i);

}
```

This example will give your td's position.

Comment: Thanks your code works, but i am looking for a tool or plugin that lets me click on an element quickly and it will tell me the position number of the specific element. Maybe a bit like the inspect element tool of firebug.

Comment: Thanks, but still not what i am looking for...

Let me clarify:

I want the number/sequence position of a specific element(e.g <img>) compared to equal elements(e.g <img>) in the whole DOM. I do not want the number of an element compared to same elements inside their parent, like your example with the cell index.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Ah well, then I don't know the answer I'm sorry.

Comment: If you try to take some of your TD's inside a new TR you will se that their position number is relative to their parent and not the whole DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Dom-tree. Every element have number if you try to get it by their XPath.

Comment: This does not work, example:

/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]

That is the xpath firebug gives me for a specific td element, but i need to know what number that TD has compared to all the TD's in the DOM.