# Get index/position of element in div - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, indexing, position

How to get the position of last child in a element, I mean the number (the index)?

I want the code below to alert "4", since there is four elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2
        <div id="child_div1">div2</div>
        <div id="child_div2">div2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">div3</div>
    <div id="div4">div4</div>
</div>
<script>

var container = document.getElementById('container'),
last_child_of_container = container.childNodes.length;

alert('position of last div is'+ last_child_of_container);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo there, should be `childNodes.length`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. But it still return 9 wich isn't what I want it to :S

Comment: @Hakan: It is counting blank text nodes I expect.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda puzzled about that myself. You want pure-javascript solution, or are you fine with using jQuery?

Comment: no I want pure javascript. Wich pure javascript was as welled documented as jquery :S

Comment: Do you want to count text nodes?

Comment: Also, 4 is the number of (non-text) nodes. The last index would be 3.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of the question: [How can I get the position of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555061/how-can-i-get-the-position-number-of-an-element/8555613). Have a look at my answer there, it may be of use.

Comment: No  kojiro, I want to count elements (any direct following tags)

Comment: josh.trow, thats true! how to fix it?

Comment: Kojiro, I think you are right! Very strange that it returns to 4 when space is removed!

Comment: not strange at all - your original mark up has loads of white space text nodes between the tags.  Those appear in the `.childNodes` property but _not_ in the `.children` list.

Comment: Yes but shouldn't the fourth chold return 3???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
document.getElementById('container').children.length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/MGnCG/

Comment: Your jsfiddle has a nother javascript code, but your example works!!! Why is it returning 4 and not 3 (the first one would be 0 a guess). Thanks

Comment: @Hakan 4 is the # of children, 3 would be the correct index, so if you wanted to get the last element you could do something like `var children = document.getElementById('container').children; var lastChild = children[children.length - 1];`

Comment: Just interested, why not lastChild = children.length - 1; ?

Comment: @Hakan the children array holds references to the children elements, so `children[children.length - 1]` returns the `<div id="div4">` element.  `children.length - 1` would only return the value `3`.  just depends on what need

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6266/discussion-between-hakan-and-mdmullinax)

Answer (score 2):

This works :-)

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var count = 0;
var length = container.childNodes.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (container.childNodes[i].tagName && 
        container.childNodes[i].tagName == 'DIV') {
        count += 1;
    }
}

alert(count);
```

Comment: did +1 you, but then removed it for using `for ... in ...`

Comment: replaced with regular `for` loop. What's wrong with `for in`?

Comment: This works, but it loops over the indices of a nodeList, which is dangerous. What if `container.childNodes[childItem]` is a property or text node that doesn't have a tagName property?

Comment: It's slower and the order isn't guaranteed, basically useless for arrays and array likes when you have `for`

Comment: it's the wrong mechanism for iterating over an array-like structure. `for ... in ...` is for object properties.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev what's wrong is that for … in loops over all properties of an object, which may include inherited properties and non-indices. And order is not guaranteed.

Comment: You should also consider storing the result of `container.childNodes.length` in a variable instead of calculating it in every iteration. It might look like a cheap operation outside but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Give `document.getElementById('container').childElementCount` a go

Comment: Thanks but, MDN says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.childElementCount

Comment: MDN says "_Don't use it. Support might be dropped in future versions of Gecko. See bug 673790_".

Answer (score 0):

Add h at the end of `container.childNodes.lengt`

```
    container.childNodes.length;
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ensangalufu/r6HR7/)

For immediate child use `childElementCount`

```
   container.childElementCount;
```

Comment: This will include all child elements and I believe the op is only after the immediate children.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/2t3VJ/

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'), children = 0;
for( var i=0, c = container.childNodes, l = c.length ; i < l; i++ ) {

   if( c[i].nodeType == 1 ) { // if this is a HTMLSomeELement :)
       children++;
   }
}

alert( children );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = window.document.getElementById("container");
var child_nodes = container.childNodes;
var child_nodes_length = child_nodes.length;
var count = 0;
var node;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < child_nodes_length; i++) {
    node = child_nodes.item(i);
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        ++count;
    }
}

window.alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who wants any element (e.g. not necessarily the last one)

```
var wanted = document.getElementById('wanted');
var index = [].indexOf.call(wanted.parentElement.children, wanted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to get the position of the last element ... people are making it so complicated... try my code

```
function getLastElPos(container) {
   return container.childNodes.length;
}
```

it returns the length of the child nodes in the container element, and the length means the last element (lol).

you can use it like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var lastElement = getLastElPos( container );

alert( lastElement );
```

it works fine in all browser :)